# UIPageViewController + UIImagePicker with custom controls not working - view is not in window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to create effect similar to Snapchat in Swift - swiping between **UIImagePicker** with custom controls and other VCs.

The problem is:

- when **CameraVC** is presented for the first time background is black and swipe between VCs works only on controls (on empty space where should be image from camera it isn't) and warning shows up "Attempt to present UIImagePickerController on CameraVC whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"
- when I swipe to another VC and then back to **CameraVC** UIImagePicker is presented properly and everything works great instead of swiping between VCs which is not working at all. There's also no "window hierarchy" warning

So I think the reason why it's not working is that **UIImagePicker** is presenting over **PageViewController** not "in" it, but I have no idea how to fix this.

I'm presenting **PageViewController** like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var vcPageView = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewID") as! UIViewController
    self.presentViewController(vcPageView, animated: false, completion: nil)    
}
```

Loading VCs to table in **PageViewController**:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.delegate = self
    self.dataSource = self

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    var vc0 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CameraID") as! UIViewController
    var vc1 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vc2ID") as! UIViewController

    self.myViewControllers = [vc0, vc1]

    self.setViewControllers([myViewControllers[0]], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

}
```

And finally **CameraVC**:

```
@IBOutlet var cameraOverlay: UIView!
var camera = UIImagePickerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()  

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera){


        self.camera.delegate = self
        self.camera.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
        self.camera.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage]
        self.camera.allowsEditing = false
        self.camera.showsCameraControls = false

        self.cameraOverlay.frame = self.camera.cameraOverlayView!.frame

        self.cameraOverlay.bringSubviewToFront(self.cameraOverlay)
        self.camera.cameraOverlayView = self.cameraOverlay

        self.cameraOverlay = nil

    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.topMostViewController().presentViewController(self.camera, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

**topMostViewController** code:

```
extension UIViewController {
func topMostViewController() -> UIViewController {
    // Handling Modal views
    if let presentedViewController = self.presentedViewController {
        return presentedViewController.topMostViewController()
    }
        // Handling UIViewController's added as subviews to some other views.
    else {
        for view in self.view.subviews
        {
            // Key property which most of us are unaware of / rarely use.
            if let subViewController = view.nextResponder() {
                if subViewController is UIViewController {
                    let viewController = subViewController as! UIViewController
                    return viewController.topMostViewController()
                }
            }
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this, In the CameraVC move the camera code in the `viewDidLoad()` to the `viewDidAppear()`